# How to solve such a system of quadratic equations: $x^2+y^2-xy=a^2, x^2+z^2-xz=b^2, y^2+z^2-yz=c^2$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I don't know how to solve this this system:
$$x^2+y^2-xy=a^2\\x^2+z^2-xz=b^2\\y^2+z^2-yz=c^2$$ The system of quadratic equation in symmetry form has many geometric meaning,
this seems to be a triangular pyramid, three adjacent angles with a common point are $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and opposite to this point is a triangle with $a,b,c$.

> But this geometric meaning makes no sense to me, it can't simplify the problem. I don't have other idea about it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the $xy$, $yz$, and $xz$ terms?

Comment: What I did was rewrite the above 3 equations in terms of cosine formula, then construct three triangles together so that it looks like a trapezium. Then, you will get three congruent triangles, from where you'll get a=b=c,and x=y=z. Not sure if this is right, someone please advise

Comment: I don't think so.  If you eliminate the $xy$ term in the first equation, you find it's an elliptical cylinder whose axis is the $z$-axis, and that the axes of the ellipse in the $xy$-plane are the $45^\circ$ lines.  Analogous statements will be true of the other two equations, so we're looking for the intersection of $3$ elliptical cylinders.  My spatial visualization is awful, but I don't think it's necessary to have $a=b=c$.  (This was addressed to Smriti, not to Jet.)

Comment: @saulspatz, I have try to remove the term of  xy,yz,xz, but when I remove one of it , other equation will produce new cross terms and lose its symmetry.

Comment: @swordblack Yes, that's true.  I wasn't suggesting this would solve the problem, just give a geometric realization of it that runs counter to the OP's intuition.

Comment: @swordblack, I didn't understand. Do you want both the solution as well as the geometric meaning? Geometric visualization need not necessarily simplify the problem.

Comment: @ cosmo5,  I just want the solution. Geometric meaning is a way I try to use, because I have met similiar problem where the sign of xy,yz,xz is "+" rather than  "-",. In that case, We can convert it into Fermat point then using the such geometric meaning we can solve it easily. In this problem I have no idea, the geometry is just a try.

Comment: "+" case was planar, with slight restriction on $a,b,c$ that they do not form obtuse triangle for trivial solutions. Then Fermat point would produce unique solution.

Comment: But from @saulpastz's comment, "-" case is intersection volume of 3 elliptical cylinders, which will produce a finite volume ie, infinite solutions for appropriate, fixed $a,b,c$. I'm still trying to figure out the solution. Just wanted to point out this much.

Comment: Yes, I notice the "-" case will be more flexible, but why it will produce infinite solution?  I solve the system by Mathematica and it give me finite answer. although the form is  complicated(even horror maybe).

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
(y+z-x)(y-z)&=y^2-z^2-xy+xz=a^2-b^2\\
(x+y-z)(x-y)&=x^2-y^2-zx+zy=b^2-c^2\\
(z+x-y)(z-x)&=z^2-x^2-yz+yx=c^2-a^2
\end{align}

Let $u:=y-z$, $v:=y+z$, $\alpha^2:=a^2-b^2$, $\beta^2:=b^2-c^2$, $\gamma^2:=c^2-a^2$, then
\begin{align}
(v-x)u&=\alpha^2\\
(x+u)(u+v-2x)&=-2\beta^2\\
(x-u)(v-u-2x)&=2\gamma^2
\end{align}

Eliminating $x=v-\frac{\alpha^2}{u}$, (unless $\alpha=0=u$) \begin{align}
(uv+u^2-\alpha^2)(u^2+uv-2uv+2\alpha^2)&=-2\beta^2u^2\\
(uv-u^2-\alpha^2)(uv-u^2-2uv+2\alpha^2)&=2\gamma^2u^2\\
\therefore\ (u^2+uv-\alpha^2)(u^2-uv+2\alpha^2)&=-2\beta^2u^2\\
(u^2-uv+\alpha^2)(u^2+uv-2\alpha^2)&=2\gamma^2u^2\\
\therefore\ (u^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha^2)^2-(uv-\tfrac{3}{2}\alpha^2)^2&=-2\beta^2u^2\\
(u^2-\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha^2)^2-(uv-\tfrac{3}{2}\alpha^2)^2&=2\gamma^2u^2
\end{align}

These two equations are actually the same: $$ (u^2-\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha^2)^2-(u^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha^2)^2=-2\alpha^2u^2=2(\beta^2+\gamma^2)u^2$$

So we get $$v=\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\alpha^2\pm\sqrt{(u^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha^2)^2+2\beta^2u^2}\right)/u$$

It seems we've lost one degree of freedom. This is due to taking differences of the equations to start with. So reintroduce the $y,z$ equation as $$(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2+(u+v)(u-v)=4c^2$$ $$3u^2+v^2=4c^2$$ Substituting $v$ in this equation gives a quartic in $u^2$, which can be solved.

Hence find $v$, $y$, $z$, $x$ in turn.

Note: There may be 8 or 4 or 0 real solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is what I want, It is an amazing substitution which can make full use of the symmetry.

Comment: Nice, beat me to it!  Serves me right for doing that 1400-ft stair climb before solving this math problem!

Comment: Impressive.  Can you explain the note at the end about the number of real solutions?  Is this easy to see on general principles, or does one have to analyze the quartic?

Comment: I think he writes the notes of number of the solutions to emphasize the real coefficient of the equation which has an influence on the solution, it is just caused by the symmetry of the problem. It might can be understanded by the figure of the equations which is three intersecting cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the first and second equations as quadratic in $y$ and $z$ to get four pairs of solutions

$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2}\right)\qquad z=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x-\sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2}\right)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2}\right)\qquad z=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x+\sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2}\right)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(x+\sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2}\right)\qquad z=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x-\sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2}\right)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(x+\sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2}\right)\qquad z=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x+\sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2}\right)$$

Suppose that the last is the "good" one, replace in the third equation which is
$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)-\frac{5 x^2}{4}+\frac x 4\left(\sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2}+\sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2} \right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{4 a^2-3 x^2} \sqrt{4 b^2-3 x^2}=0$$

I suppose that multiple squaring steps would lead to an octic equation in $x$ which, I hope, could be factorized.

However, for given values of $(a,b,c)$, I would prefer to graph the function to locate more or less the solution and after to use Newton method for the solution in $x$ and then $y$ and $z$.